# GraphQL schema query not recognizing passed input parameters in the resolver function

Tags: node.js, graphql

I defined the below query in my GraphQL schema

```
type Query {        
    getShowByName(showSchemaName: String!): String!        
}
```

with the corresponding resolver function as shown below

```
const resolvers = ()=>({
    Query:{

        getShowByName: function(args){
            console.log("out1"+args);
            console.log("out3"+args.showSchemaName);            
            return "hardcoded return from getShowByName";           
        },        
    },    
});
```

In the graphql playground, i provided the below inputs

```
{
  getShowByName(showSchemaName:"input to getShowByName")  
}
```

The graphql playground provides *hardcoded return from getShowByName* as output in the playground page but in the terminal i get args as undefined. Hence, i am unable to parse the input fed in from the graphql playground.

Please help me in understanding where i am going wrong and how i can rectify the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument in the resolver is an object that contains the result of parent resolver. In your case, the root level `Query` will receive `undefined`. Instead you should extract the `args` from the second argument.

```
const resolvers = ()=> ({
    Query: {
        getShowByName: function(_, args) {
            console.log("out1" + args);
            console.log("out3" + args.showSchemaName);            
            return "hardcoded return from getShowByName";           
        },        
    },    
});
```